# Selectable UITableViewCells when UITableView is in editing mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

The title says everything. I need to make selecting of the `UITableViewCells` possible when UITableView is in the editing mode. I don't think that code is necessary here, but in case it is:

```
-(void)turnEditingOn {
  [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
  if (self.tableView.isEditing)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(newItem)];
  else
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(turnEditingOn)];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(turnEditingOn)];
  //the rest of the code is omitted
}
```

So I need to be able to make taps on the cells when it's in the editing mode, just like the Clock app when you are editing alarms.

Thank you

*EDIT*

Forgot to mention:

```
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

are not getting called in the editing mode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
}
```